# How to calculate any power of a base 2 number in Java by not using BigInteger?

Tags: java, binary

How can I calculate in Java any power of a number in a base 2 (2^n, where n can be any number), without using the `BigInteger` class?

Let's say I got the binary number 100000000000000000000100000000001 stored in a given array, and I want to print its value in a decimal number (just to print it, let's say we store it in a String type).

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @imraklr I'm asking for ideas regarding to how to calculate/solve the given problem, I couldn't think of a solution so I don't have a working code... I'd just like to understand the direction of the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem completely, but if n is the binary number converted to a decimal number, then you are playing with way too large numbers.

Consider the binary number as decimal. Your example would be the decimal number 4294969345. Just try to consider what 2^4294969345 would be. As an example 2^429 would be 1.38633485×10^129. There's no way you can execute this.

I agree with the others, please share your code, and maybe you can get a better answer.

EDIT: If it's just a conversion from the big binary number to a decimalnumber, you can use Long.parseLong(binaryNumber, 2), where binaryNumber is your binary number as a String.

Comment: My problem is that I want to print the value of a very big binary number - lets say the number: 100000000000000000000100000000001, and I want to print it in its decimal value, but without using BigInteger class, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The values needs to be saved somewhere to be "just printed", whether a data structure or a primitive, in your case it's way too large for an integer ( > 2^31), you can use long instead `(Long.parseLong(binary, 2))`  but eventually if it keeps getting bigger, you will need another way, either using `BigInteger` or your own brains.